# MVC4 - how to vaildate a drop down list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a .Net MVC4 model / view with a number of [Required] fields, one of which is selected via a drop down list, "Content_CreatedBy" [the first code block below].

Client side validation fires on all fields except the DDL [although server side validation does not allow no entry in DDL]. I have tried validating on the DDL text as well its numeric value but niether fire on the client side.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
**Model**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Author")]
[ForeignKey("ContentContrib")]
[Range(1, 99, ErrorMessage = "Author field is required.")]
public virtual int Content_CreatedBy { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public virtual DateTime Content_CreatedDate { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "Source / Notes ")]
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3)]
public virtual string Content_Sources { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Keywords")]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
public virtual string Content_KeyWords { get; set; }
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy, new { @class="whitelabel"})
</div>

<div class="editor-field">

@Html.DropDownList("Content_CreatedBy", String.Empty)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy)
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `DropDownListFor` also `YourSelectList` as follows;

```
<div class="editor-field">

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy, 
                                  YourSelectList,
                                 "[ -- Please Select --]") 
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy)

</div>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, it looks logical but I can't figure out the syntax to get my select List into "YourSelectList" - I pass the select list to the View in a Viewbag thus....    ViewBag.Content_CreatedBy = new SelectList(db.tbl_Contributers, "ID", "Initials", editViewData);
            return View(editViewData);

Comment: In the controller action set `ViewBag.CreatedByList = new SelectList(db.tbl_Contributers, "ID", "Initials")` and then in the view `(SelectList)(ViewData["CreatedByList"])`. Don't use same name `Content_CreatedBy` for the ViewBag item, it confuses model binder.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `Content_CreatedBy` nullable.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Author")]
[ForeignKey("ContentContrib")]
[Range(1, 99, ErrorMessage = "Author field is required.")]
public virtual int? Content_CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your property is of integrt type it always initializes to 0 if no matching binder found, hence it never gives u client vaidation,

workaround, change type to string, also use somethings like this.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Author")]
[ForeignKey("ContentContrib")]
[Range(1, 99, ErrorMessage = "Author field is required.")]
public virtual string Content_CreatedBy { get; set; }



Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Content_CreatedBy, 
                              IEnumerable<object>,
                             " -- Please Select --")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer - yes I see that it will always have a value, hence the range 1 - 99 should be fired on zero.